# how to stretching SVG in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

**How can i stretch svg image ?

the code is:**

```
child: SvgPicture.asset(   
                  'assets/images/accessories.svg',
                  height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.5,
                  width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.8,
                ),
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the fit property for SvgPicture widget to provide the fitting on the asset image according to need.
Some of the properties for fit are

## BoxFit.contain

As large as possible while still containing the source entirely within the target box.

## BoxFit.cover

As small as possible while still covering the entire target box.

## BoxFit.fill

Fill the target box by distorting the source's aspect ratio.

## BoxFit.fitHeight

Make sure the full height of the source is shown, regardless of whether this means the source overflows the target box horizontally.

## BoxFit.fitWidth

Make sure the full width of the source is shown, regardless of whether this means the source overflows the target box vertically.

## BoxFit.none

Align the source within the target box (by default, centering) and discard any portions of the source that lie outside the box.

## BoxFit.scaleDown

As large as possible while still containing the source entirely within the target box.

For more detailed reference see [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fit property for the SvgPicture widget this way below.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/bg.svg'),
          ),
```

Comment: How does this add anything to the answer posted around a year and a half ago?